# Python, How do I concatenate Strings and Array of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays

The following is what I want to do (but I know it does not work).

```
msg["X-RECIP-ID"] = emailData['campaignId'] + "-" emailData['listId'] + "-" emailData['emailId'])
```

I know join(array, "-"), can do it for an array [campaignId, listId, emailId], but what I have currently have afaik is an array in an array.

What would be Pythonic way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: `''.join(list) + "-" ...`

Comment: in your example I see only strings. Where is the array?

Comment: emailData['campaignId'] is the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have with `emailData` isn't an array, or an array of arrays (or even a list of lists), but instead it's a `Dictionary` (see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries )

What I think you want to do is pull out certain values out of this dictionary into a new list, and then use the `join` method to put them all together with a "-" between them.

`msgElems = [emailData[i] for i in ['campaignId', 'listId', 'emailId']]
msg["X-RECIP-ID"] = "-".join(msgElems)`

Comment: Always post an explanation with code, just code answers are often poor.

Comment: beautiful, whaet I was looking for.

Comment: @Rich you're right, I tried to add some context.